# Serial numbers from Monitors

Tags: vba, serial-number

I can get the serial numbers from all attached monitors with the Powershell command:

```
get-wmiobject wmimonitorid -namespace root\wmi|foreach-object{($_.SerialnumberID|foreach-object{[char]$_}) -join „“}
```

Is it possible to do this with VBA?

My intention is to add the serial numbers to Excel (one serial number per cell).

Comment: Is this about how to control Excel through PowerShell? If so, start reading up about this. A simple google-search got me [here](http://woshub.com/read-write-excel-files-powershell/). Now you have a way of how to control Excel, you can start thinking about how to write each serialnumber into a different cell, instead of the -join operation you now perform with the 'foreach-object'. If your intention is to ask about VBA, then you need to include your own VBA-code for debugging purposes. Otherwise the question is off-topic and should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to add WMI scripting library to the references

```
Sub getMonitors()
    Dim m As SWbemObject
    Dim c
    For Each m In GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\WMI").ExecQuery _
        ("SELECT SerialNumberID FROM WmiMonitorID")
        For Each c In m.serialNumberID
            Debug.Print Chr(c);
        Next
        Debug.Print
    Next
End Sub
```

You can change debug.print to add to certain cells instead, by using `Dim s as String` and `s = s + chr(c);`

Comment: Many many thanks - it work perfect.
I have added the Reference "Microsoft WMI Scripting (1.2 Library)"